# GIT: Generated .bin symlinks prevent adding node_modules to repo

Tags: node.js, git

I've used `npm install` to install node dependencies. I wish to push those new packages to my repo, however when I run `git add *` the following error is thrown:

```
error: readlink("node_modules/.bin/JSONStream"): Function not implemented
error: unable to index file node_modules/.bin/JSONStream
fatal: adding files failed
```

Now, I'm working on Windows 7 and I undestand the OS has problems with the symlinks stored in `.bin` directories created during `npm install`. The error above is just an example. If I remove the `.bin` directory from `node_modules` root, there will be another one in one of the packages directly, and another...

I tried running the installation with `--no-bin-links` flag but it always ends with the error: "Maximum call stack size exceeded".

As an additional info, the `npm_install` is ran in virtual environment (Laravel's Homestead).

How can I get solve the problem to safely commit my node_modules with GIT?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `.bin` line in your top level `.gitignore` file. This will prevent any folder with this name to be added so you can push your dependencies.